# anyone know how to make this bubble shooter movement in swift

Tags: swift, rotation

I would like to rotate a rectangle so that the bottom remains fixed and the top moves left and right to a given extent. kinda like this old style bubble shooter: http://prntscr.com/ab05a8
this is what id basically need the rectangle to do: http://prntscr.com/ab05om

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your rectangle is an instance of `UIView`, you can set it's anchor to the middle of the button edge:

```
yourView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1.0)
```

Then, you can rotate it's `layer` using `CATransform3D`. For example by 45 degrees:

```
var transform = yourView.layer.transform
transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, CGFloat(45.0 * M_PI / 180.0), 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
yourView.layer.transform = transform
```